# comparison of annotate objects in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to remove the annotation of an element in a scatter plot when that element has received a second click. I am comparing the new annotation to a list of annotations that currently appear on the plot. I am getting what seems to be equivalent values however my comparison is returning false. What am I missing?

Here is the onPick event code that produces the annotation:

```
def displayval(self, ax):
    def onPick(event):

        thispoint = event.artist
        xval = thispoint.get_xdata()
        yval = thispoint.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind

        if xval[ind].size > 1 or yval[ind].size > 1: return

        xy = (xval[ind][0], yval[ind][0])

        ann = ax.annotate('(%f , %f)' % xy, xy= xy)


        for elem in self.annotatedPoints:
            print(ann)
            print(elem)
            print (ann == elem)
            if ann  == elem:
                ann.remove()
                elem.remove()
                return

        self.annotatedPoints.append(ann)            

    self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onPick)
    return onPick
```

here is the return value of the print statements when ran and the same element is selected twice.

```
Annotation(3326,0.0262,'(3326.000000 , 0.026200)')
Annotation(3326,0.0262,'(3326.000000 , 0.026200)')
False
```

Edit: 
Complete Working Example

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class eventerror():
    def __init__(self):

        self.annotatedPoints = []

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)

        xarray = [1,4,5,3,2,3]
        yarray = [7,8,2,4,3,9]
        val = self.displayval(ax)
        ax.plot(xarray, yarray, 'o', picker = 5)

        plt.show()

    def displayval(self, ax):
        def onPick(event):

            thispoint = event.artist
            xval = thispoint.get_xdata()
            yval = thispoint.get_ydata()
            ind = event.ind

            if xval[ind].size > 1 or yval[ind].size > 1: return

            xy = (xval[ind][0], yval[ind][0])

            ann = ax.annotate('(%f , %f)' % xy, xy= xy)
            plt.show()


            for elem in self.annotatedPoints:
                print(ann)
                print(elem)
                print (ann == elem)
                if ann  == elem:
                    ann.remove()
                    elem.remove()
                    return

            self.annotatedPoints.append(ann)            

        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onPick)
        return onPick

if __name__ == '__main__':
    err = eventerror()
```

Solution:

```
    for elem in self.annotatedPoints:
        if ann.xy = elem.xy:
            ann.remove()
            elem.remove()
            self.annotatedPoints.remove(elem)
            return
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have updated the question per your suggestion.

Comment: What happens if you feed it a dataset with two values with the same `xy`? Do you get two annotations with the same `xy`, and does the code behave reasonably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Annotation` constructor accepts `xytext`, `arrowprops`, and several other optional attributes which `__str__()` does not reveal. You might see them with `repr()`. I recommend you write your own equality predicate which extracts the specific items of interest, like x & y, and tests those.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. I was able to match on one of the attributes of the annotation, xy, and get the correct comparison value.